# ¿Cómo puedo asignar el tamaño de los Grid.Row?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows, wpf

Estoy haciendo por primera vez una aplicación `Desktop` en WPF y hay muchas cosas que no entiendo.

Por ejemplo, tengo definida esta ventana con un `StackPanel` donde defino un `Grid` para poder ordenar bien las 3 partes de la ventana (Cabecera, cuerpo y pie).

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackMain">
    <Grid x:Name="GridBotones">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Cabecera-->
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Grid.Row="0" Content="Prueba de la Cabecera" />

        <!--Cuerpo-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgClientes" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

        <!--Pie-->
        <Button x:Name="btnActualizar" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Actualizar" />
        <Button x:Name="btnCerrar" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="X" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Mi problema es que cuando ejecuto esto, la ventana se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero que los botones de `Actualizar` y `X` queden en la parte inferior de la ventana.
Me da la sensasión que estuviera omitiendo el `<RowDefinition Height="9*"/>`

Hace bastantes horas que estoy trabado con esto y no sé como resolverlo.

Comment: Coloca el Grid sin StackPanel, y lo ajustes en ancho y alto automático. Si lo colocas dentro de un StackPanel se va a ajustar hacia un extremo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con esto simplemente deberia funcionar:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridBotones">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Cabecera-->
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Grid.Row="0" Content="Prueba de la Cabecera" />

        <!--Cuerpo-->
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgClientes" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>

        <!--Pie-->
        <Button x:Name="btnActualizar" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Actualizar" />
        <Button x:Name="btnCerrar" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="X" />
    </Grid>
```

También puedes omitir el Height="*" ya que es lo que hace por defecto.